# Which Xcorr to choose in a concrete situation: normalized/not, biased/unbiased?

Tags: cross-correlation

I have 2 data sets, one is binned and another is not, 9000 values each. Something like this:

`a = [23 45 88 9 0 29 30 60 0 2 10 100 0 60 90] b = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]` Actually, the `b` is the set of events (yes/no) which occurs during a continuous change of the intensity of a "signal" (the signal has values [0–100]). I performed the cross-correlation, because I want to find if the occurrence of the events has something in common with the changes of a signal.

So I did:

```
maxlags = 300; [c, lags] = xcorr(a-mean(a), b-mean(b), maxlags, 'coeff')
```

And I also created a 10-times shuffled null-hypothesis:

```
    urge_shuffled=urge_new;
a_sh = a;
b_sh=b;
all_corr_rand_norm=[];
for k=1:10
    a_sh1 = a_shuff(randperm(length(a_sh)));
    a_sh = a_sh11;
    b_sh1 =b_sh(randperm(length(b_sh)));
    b_sh=b_sh1;
    [c_sh,lags]=xcorr(a_sh-mean(a_sh),b_sh-mean(b_sh),maxlags, 'coeff');
    all_corr_rand_norm (k,:) =c_sh;
end
    corr_rand=mean(all_corr_rand_norm);`
```

and also calculated the *t*-score values.
So finally I've got such a thing:

[image]

At first I tried to do the correlation just with `xcorr(a,b, maxlags, coeff)` without subtracting the mean, but in this case it gives me a very strange null hypothesis (it's in red; the real correlation is in blue; the changes are more evident with bigger maxlags):
[image]

It's clearly a triangle. I did some research on the internet and even found some similar questions, but the answers were that this is because of "zero-padding", and that's why we should subtract the mean before the correlation.

Here is my 1st question: **why in some cases do people get a nice null-hypothesis even with `xcorr(a,b)` – what does it depend on?**

The second question is **whether or not it's right in my case to subtract the mean** – basically, it already corresponds to the `xcov` function of MATLAB, and this is already the covariance... (I also have a colleague who suggested I use the `xcorr` and afterwards to subtract the mean:

```
[c, lags]= xcorr(a,b, maxlags, 'coeff')
x_crr=c-mean(c)
```

—but I don't really see why I should do it, and besides, it still gives me the same strange triangle-shaped null-hypothesis.

The 3rd question is: **are the cross-covariance and cross-correlation so different in my case?** Yes, I've already read all that I could find about them both, but the phrases, "The covariance shows how 2 functions variate together when the cross-correlation shows their correlation," didn't help too much. If something varies with a specific lag before/after the other function, isn't it the correlation?

Also, while searching for the explanation of my triangulated null-hypothesis, I saw somebody's advice to use the "'unbiased' cross-correlation", while others strongly suggested to not do this. So the 4th question is, **when do we actually use this unbiased/biased `xcorr`?** I've found again mostly "great" descriptions that the "biased cross-correlation is biased, while unbiased is not." There were some better answers, of course, but I still don't get it.

And, the last question: in my case, as I have a significant *t* but a weak correlation between both sets of values, can we affirm that the fluctuations of both sets of data are almost independent?

I perfectly understand that it's a mix of common and probably easy questions about the cross-correlation, but the explanations that I’ve found on the internet usually sound dubious or are not really like explanations, but just some fast assertions (like "the unbiased means is unbiased") and I feel unsure about interpreting my findings.